# Remove all padding and margin table HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html-table, margin, padding

I have this table :

```
<body>
    <table id="page" >
        <tr id="header" >
            <td colspan="2" id="tdheader" >je suis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and here is the css

```
html, body, #page {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

and I want to remove all margin and padding but always I have that :

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try to use this CSS:

```css
/* Apply this to your `table` element. */
#page {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* And this to your table's `td` elements. */
#page td {
   padding: 0; 
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
table { 
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: border-spacing doesn't work when border-collapse in collapse mode.

Comment: @IvanZ It was years ago, so I don't remember exactly, but there were some broken browsers which needed that.

Answer (score 8):

Tables are odd elements. Unlike `div`s they have special rules. Add `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes, set to `0`, and it should fix the problem.

```
<table id="page" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Comment: The accepted answer uses css padding and margin, which is the recommended alternative to cellspacing and cellpadding, which have been deprecated for many years now.  And note that HTML5 does not support cellspacing and cellpadding.

Answer (score 8):

Use a display block

```
style= "display: block";
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using tag body to remove all margin and padding like that you want.

```
<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0">
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor=green>
        <tr>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove padding between cells inside the table. Just use `cellpadding=0` and `cellspacing=0` attributes in table tag.

Comment: It should be better to use CSS instead of deprecated attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I find the most perfectly working answer is this

```
.noBorder {
    border: 0px;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
That is a table with collapsed borders and <IMG images in each <TD cell.
I had padding and margin set to zero on everything.
Nothing would get rid of the bottom padding of the <IMG

Changing the CSS attribute of the <IMG tag to "display: block;" solved it.
Thank-you - user yoko

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove Padding from Left and right side :

padding:0;
margin:0;

for Table cell padding remove :

cellpadding : 0;
cellspacing : 0;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).